# Paste preset html code via Applescript into text edit

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Hi so I want to preset specific line of html code, and then paste it with key combo using Applescript.

Here is the html code:

```
<li> 
<div class="topic-title"> 
<h2>Topic title goes here</h2> 
</div> 
</li>
```

I want Applescript to paste all of this html code into my text editor using a key combo. I tried a script but it gets confused by the quotes in the html code itself. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: If all you need help with is the quotes within the HTML _code_, then simple escape the quotes with a backslash, e.g.: `\"topic-title\"`. You could do something like, e.g. `set the clipboard to "<li>" & linefeed & "<div class=\"topic-title\">" & linefeed & "<h2>Topic title goes here</h2>" & linefeed & "</div>" & linefeed & "</li>"` then activate the target app, then use **System Events** to paste it, e.g.: `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down`

Comment: If you're using something like **TextWrangler** or **BBEdit** you can use their `paste` _command_ instead of **System Events**. Or you could just set up a text replacement where you'd type something and it would be replaced with the HTML _code_.  **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text**

Comment: I searched on google but Bbedit has no way to store custom code and paste when required. Any suggestions regarding this BBEdit feature? Thanks!

Comment: I'd use text replacement as IMO its the easiest way to go. As an example, all the worlds in **bold** or _italics_ in my other comments are text replacements.  E.g. I type `cmd` and it get replaced with `_command_` and shows as _command_. Almost everything I write more than a few times I've setup a text replacement for. You could use e.g. `topt` and have it replaced with the HTML _code_ in your OP

Comment: Well I just found BBEdit feature Clippings will do this easily 

Comment: I invested the $5 USD in a program called [aText](https://trankynam.com/atext/) (I'm not affiliated) It's a text expansion app that picks up where Apple's built in text replacement fails (as in all apps must support it - i.e. Firefox doesn't).  With a simple text code, I insert signatures, HTML snippits, or whatever code I have have programmed in

Comment: [_QuickWords_](https://github.com/quickwords/quickwords) is open source via GitHub, actively maintained and been going for some time, and you can create JavaScript-led expansions.  But it's made with electronJS.  If one is considering paying, I thoroughly recommend `Typinator`, which is powerful and resource-efficient.  However, since the situation described in the OP is dealing with `TextEdit`—which is scriptable—inserting text into a new or an existing document using AppleScript is simple and should probably be the first recommendation.

Comment: Just realised, it actually doesn't matter whether or not the application in question is scriptable.  Since the OP wishes to create a key-combo that triggers an insertion of the given text—and assuming we won't rely on third-party apps to get involved—@sd100 will be glad to know that this is simple to do using _Automator_ to create a Quick Action, in which there's an option labelled _`Output replaces selected text`_, which is the dog's bollocks. With this checked, there's zero AppleScript, zero coding, and once the key combo is assigned (_System Preferences_), it will function in any app. QED

Comment: BBEdit has an advanced clippings feature. Don't google when you can visit the product page and read the actual feature set. http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/featuresweb.html "Powerful Clippings system: store and insert frequently used text items and custom tags; with menu-driven and key-bindable item selection; language-sensitive sets (sample C Source, CSS, HTML, Property List, RSS, Ruby, Ruby-in-HTML, and WML clippings sets supplied, with more contributed by the BBEdit user community)"

Comment: Yep BBEdit does have an excellent clipping feature which is now use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 'service' in Automator.

Give it the following settings: 
Service receives 'no input' in 'any application'
Check 'Output replaces selected text'

Add the following 'Actions'
Get Specified Text - insert your clip here
Copy to Clipboard
Run AppleScript - replace the (* your script *) with 'the clipboard'

Click the 'Run' button to test the workflow. If there are no issues here, save the service.

To test whether the service works, put the cursor in a text doc of some sort (any place that you can paste multi-line text) and right-click… you should see the service's name in the menu. Click it and see what happens. Hopefully, it will paste your clipping into the text area which the cursor is in.

If it works well, go to the System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and click Services. Scroll through the resulting list on the right to find the name of your newly created service (should be in the Text section). Give it a keyboard shortcut (hopefully one that doesn't conflict with any other), and you're done.

So what does the service do? You specify the text for the clipping, it copies that to the clipboard. The applescript pastes the clipboard wherever you trigger the service.

As an aside, you don't mention what text editor you're using which might make it easier to devise a solution. BBedit was mentioned in the comments but the are other apps such as Coda that also offer some variation of a clippings feature. And as a further aside, I am unable to include a screenshot with my post.

Comment: Yes thanks so much. I am now using BBEdit which has clipping feature.

Comment: Good to hear. I didn't notice that comment when I wrote mine. BBEdit is a great app.